# Git: Remove files after push

Tags: git

I have a local repository at my workstation and remote repository on server (phpfog.com). My application generates cache files and I want to delete them (on the remote) everytime someone pushes: is it possible and if so - how? FYI: These files are ignored using .gitignore (maybe there might be a way how to use this).

I've heard of git hooks but have little idea how to use them.

Thank you

Edit: I want to do git clean (remove untracked files) but on the remote and with every push. These files are generated by application and this cannot be solved by .gitignore-ing them (in fact they are gitignored).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think post-receive hook is what you are looking for.

Just add a bash script to remote server which clean all cache file and specify it as post-receive hook. For more information look at http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html

Comment: Using this will solve the problem, but making file system maintenance a dependency on Git sounds utterly wrong to me.

Comment: sciritai: I have explained it below. It is not a "filesystem maintenance" it is an action directly connected with pushing and nothing else.

Comment: Alexandr: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I need. Now I need to figure out how to change git settings on the server (but I'm not sure if it is possible, I hope technical support will reply soon)

Answer (score 1):

Why are people pushing files that are better ignored? Just `git rm --cached` them  and commit and push. Make sure they are properly added to the `.gitignore` and it would make sure people are not accidentally adding these files again and pushing them.

Comment: I hope I have not misunderstood what you meant. But the cached files are generated when the application runs on server. Of couse I ignore them when commiting on my workstation. But I also need to remove cache files which origin on the remote. Thanks for answer

Comment: In that case you should update your application to perform maintenance on the cached files. This doesn't sound like a question about git if you're talking about cleaning up files on a production server.

Comment: How the application should know it was updated? Git rewrites its code and this new code might not be working with the old cache so I hoped there would be a way how to remove contents of folders mentioned in gitignore right after push.

Comment: Is your project `.gitignore` checked into git ? If the files are specified in .gitignore they wouldn't need to be removed from the git index, they wouldn't even make it in

Comment: Yes, they're in .gitignore. They are generated everytime when the application runs. Even on the server. They are never commited to the repository. I need to delete them with every push.
They're not part of repository. I need to remove them with something like Clean Up in TortoiseGit - "remove untracked files".

Comment: @Ondrej: Isn't that still an application issue? If a user upgrades, do you expect them to manually remove the cache? You could certain do it with a post-receive hook (assuming you're pushing into a non-bare repo, which isn't necessarily good...) that invokes `git clean -xdf`, say. Or you could give your application version numbers which for development versions include an short SHA1, embed the version number in the cache, and when loading it, check that and delete if necessary.

Comment: Jefromi: Removing of cache is needed only when app is deployed. That's why I think it should be done in the deployment process.
I can do that in the app every time it is run, but isn't that an overhead? (And I am not talking about the time to implement that functionality and the sad look :-) at redundant code - less code, better app)
That `git clean -xdf` seems good to me; I have just to figure out how to put it on the server. Thank you